# How to validate the Access Token in OAuth 2.0?

Tags: android, python, ios, oauth-2.0, access-token

How can I validate the Access Token and how to get the information of token using Access Token?

Is this the url to validate the Access Token?

https://mydomain/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=tYPJr7F6ArYkd1Vdlh1gbhWlnz8NLA9TZmky2NpvaHZxhw14udbmFNRG1pKMKVEY&token_type=bearer

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the data taken from token (the example is from Azure auth - but it does not matter both use OAuth2).

That's how you extract the information from the Token:

in **getAuthInteractiveCallback()** or **getAuthSilentCallback()** methods:

```
private AuthenticationCallback getAuthSilentCallback() {
    return new AuthenticationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AuthenticationResult authenticationResult) {
            /* Successfully got a token, call api now */
            Log.d(TAG, "Successfully authenticated");
            Log.d(TAG, "ID Token: " + authenticationResult.getIdToken());
            Log.d(TAG, "ID Token: " + authenticationResult.getAccessToken());

            try {
                String token = authenticationResult.getIdToken();
                String token2 = token.substring(token.indexOf('.') + 1, token.lastIndexOf('.'));
                byte[] data = Base64.decode(token2, Base64.DEFAULT);
                String text = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(text);
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("emails"));
                String eMail = jsonArray.get(0).toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "eMail: " + eMail);

            } catch (JSONException ex) { }



            authResult = authenticationResult;
            state.setAuthResult(authResult);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(MsalException exception) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }
    };
}
```

In addition you can get iod, expiration time (exp), auth time (auth_time), versiov (ver)

Comment: Thanks for your response

Comment: {
    "access_token": "tYPJr7F6ArYkd1Vdlh1gbhWlnz8NLA9TZmky2NpvaHZxhw14udbmFNRG1pKMKVEY",
    "refresh_token": "G2VAeO5ifslKTVRduT4fedjTol0hEnxkXnt0j4D8fZeeJmBvVSHyaHzYqVV0UsO3",
    "id_token": "k6pjMC0kaKMTbIKtlrlf30nshiWYHFKQ12XbVrwQ92l1e4Tq7meDWDGr7dtCFgCGmDDpPxMkxgHw1Zjt8vVnftxqzxe_DOduECMr6LgNIgDNU2Qj-jOK4Y4t4Fv3539c_fA6C6P-Ae4ssb5NFvCZjtTixyH1pqA",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 599
}


am getting the access token response like above

Comment: I want to validate the access_token uaing the access_token value

Comment: I mean server side validation, If i pass the access_token to the server they will validate me based on the token. I want the exact API to validate the token in my side

Comment: You do not need to make sure you re-check the Token every time, that's why you have an expiration date.
In AOuth2 you have a function of silent login - that is already managing the whole thing with the Token, if you need to reconnect, etc.

Comment: In my scenario am using SSO login, after login i will get access token as response, For accessing the next API i need to send the access_token along with the API params, In this case server will validate or fetch the details about the access_token based on the validation only they will give response to the mobile.